# Return 0 or 1 from a method depending upon values in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am a beginner. I am unable to figure out how to write a function which will return 1, if have this property:

```
arr[0] = arr[1] + arr[2] = arr[3] + arr[4] + arr[5] = arr[6] + arr[7] + arr[8] + arr[9] = ...
```

else returns 0. The length of an array must be `n*(n+1)/2`  for some `n`.

For example, if input array is `{2, 1, 1, 4, -1, -1}`, it returns 1 because 2 = 1 + 1, 2 = 4 + -1 + -1

I have tried this:

```
public static int myArray(int[] a) {
    int len = a.length;

    if (checkLenght(len)) {
        int firstElem = a[0];
        int value = 1;
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = value; j < value + 1; j++) {
                sum += a[j];
                value++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

public static boolean checkLenght(int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        if ((i * (i + 1) / 2) == len) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, such a method should return true or false, not 1 and 0. Java has a boolean type, and you should use it. And we won't do your homework. Try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to partition input in sets of two , three , .... elements. for that I use a `pointer` to show how many elements are in this partition. firs it is 2. then it is three , ... . and I use a `temp` number to count if in this partition I have enough element or not. after I have enough element in each partition I just check sum of the element of that partition.

This should do the work:

```
public static int myArray(int[] a) {
    int len = a.length;
    if (checkLenght(len)) {
        int firstElem = a[0];
        int pointer = 2;                     // pointer that will be 2, 3, 4 , ...
        int sum = 0;                         // sum of element in each partition
        int temp = 0;                        // a temp value to check if I reach desirable number of element in this partition or not.
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) { // i<=a.length give you exception.
            temp++;                          
            sum += a[i];
            if (temp == pointer) {           // check if I have enough element.
                pointer++;                   // plus pointer by one
                temp = 0;                    // reset temp
                if (sum != firstElem)        // if in any of those partitions my needs doesnt meet I return zero.
                    return 0;
                sum = 0;                     // reset sum
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In order to really help, I think you should explain how your answer actually works.

Comment: @kaktusito If you want the truth, I'm thinking right know about how to explain this, English is not my native language and I'm not good at it so I'm just thinking right know about how to explain it in english.